# Text Overflowing in a Row, Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I'm having issues with the layout because of the long text, I've tried using `Expanded` / `Flexible` with the text that is causing the issue to fill the space it needs but it's overflowing. I know the question is asked hundred times, but I don't understand where is the mistake. I tried applying to both `Expanded` / `Flexible` to all of the Row/Columns individually and too all at the same time (mostly I was trying out layouts to try to fix it), and I still have the issue... I even tried to use the `FittedBox` with `fit: BoxFit.(all of them)`.

[image]

```
Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text("Text 1"),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          Text('TEXT 2'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 27,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA 90045, USA',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          Text('FLIGHT 3231'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

By my understanding, and do correct me if I'm wrong, applying `Expanded` / `Flexible`, `Flexible` takes only the needed space, and `Expanded` takes all available space, respecting the flex factor. So most of the time I use the Flexible widget, but this time it is not working.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **[Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) or [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) Widget** You should try to below code :

```
Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Container(
      height: 90,
      // padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 80,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Text 1"),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  Text('TEXT 2'),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 27,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '1 World Way, Los Angeles',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(height: 1),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'FLIGHT 3231',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(height: 1),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Your screen like this :
[image: Screen Like this]

Answer (score 16):

Try using `Expanded` widget with `flex` value set as per the expectation of UI filling.

**Sample Code:**

```
Center(
        child: Container(
      height: 80,
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.bus_alert),
          ),
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                width: 1,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Column(
                  children: [Text("Text 1"), Text("Text 1")],
                ),
              )),
          Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Text("1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA 90045, USA"),
                    Text("FLIGHT 3231"),
                  ],
                ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    ))
```

***Note:*** There is a limitation for the text content using. We need to make sure to set the height according to the expected text length.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

If the text is really long, then using `Expanded` will wrap the text according to the parent widget, thus leading to change in the font size. You might consider using ellipsis.

```
return Container(
  width:300  //give a width of your choice
  child: Text('Any long text',
        overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis,
         ),
     );
```

Answer (score 3):

wrap it by a container with fixed width and then use [auto_sized_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text). Or you can wrap your Text widget by FittedBox by fixed width. it would do the same approach. Feel free to add `maxLine`, `minFontSize` and `maxFontSize' in auto_sized_text. Using` Expanded`or`Flexible` only affects the size of the container when your text length is lower than the given width, and It does not help you in this situation.